# Parsing float resulting in strange decimal values

Tags: c#, parsing, floating-point

I'm attempting to parse a string with 2 decimal places as a float.

The problem is, the resultant object has an incorrect mantissa.
As it's quite a bit off what I'd expect, I struggle to believe it's a rounding issue.

[image]

However double seems to work.

This value does seem to be within the range of a float (-3.4 × 10^38 to +3.4 × 10^38) so I don't see why it doesn't parse it as I'd expect.

I tried a few more test but it doesn't make what's happening any more clear to me.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you show the code instead of images, the we could test it by ourself?

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's a watch window. That is the code. That's as simple as it gets.

Comment: It would be much easier for us to reproduce your issue if we had sample data. And we can't get it from images (will will rot anyway in future). That's why i suggested to post the variables (incl. result) instead of only images. For example: `Console.WriteLine(float.Parse("650512.5")));...` (<-- can be copy-pasted)

Comment: I think the code is self explanatory, and anything more such as Console.WriteLine is superfluous. Having said that, I concede to your point about image rot

Comment: I haven't said that the question was unclear. Imho people are more willing to help if they can reproduce your issue. It's simply more work   to enter all numbers manually instead of copy-pasting your sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for [`System.Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single):

> All floating-point numbers have a limited number of significant digits, which also determines how accurately a floating-point value approximates a real number. A Single value has up to 7 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 9 digits is maintained internally.

It's not a matter of the *range* of float - it's the *precision*.

The closest *exact* value to 650512.56 (for example) is 650512.5625... which is then being shown as 650512.5625 in the watch window.

To be honest, if you're parsing a *decimal* number, you should probably use `decimal` to represent it. That way, assuming it's in range and doesn't have more than the required number of decimal digits, you'll have the *exact* numeric representation of the original string. While you could use `double` and be fine for 9 significant digits, you still wouldn't be storing the exact value you parsed - for example, "0.1" can't be exactly represented as a `double`.

Comment: If you want to have a higher precision you could use a double datatype

Comment: Cheers, that makes sense, sort of. Double will do for now, but mental note to do further research on the floating point type system. Love your C# book by the way.

Answer (score 1):

The mantissa of a float in c# has 23 bits, which means that it can have 6-7 significant digits. In your example `650512.59` you have 8, and it is just that digit which is 'wrong'. Double has a mantissa of 52 bits (15-16 digits), so of course it will show correctly all your 8 or 9 significant digits.

See here for more: [Type float in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hd7199ke.aspx)